# En SSIS ADO NET funciona sin embargo al cambiarlo por OLE DB me falla ¿Porque?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Tengo un flujo de datos donde estoy cargando un archivo CSV a SQL Server 2012 por medio de SSIS. Todo me funciona bien cuando el destino tiene la cadena de conexion ADO NET, pero necesito cambiar la cadena de conexion por OLE DB. Al realizar el cambio y ejecutarlo me genera el siguiente error:

**[OLE DB Destination [241]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".**

lo curioso es que si abro el archivo CSV con Excel y elimino alguna fila al azar, vuelvo y pruebo y con eso si me funciona perfectamente el cambio a OLE DB.

¿que esta pasando?

Agradezco su amable ayuda

Comment: Y si haces lo mismo pero en vez de abrir con excel y eliminar, abres con notepad y eliminas. A lo mejor la clave la tienes en la codificacion que guardas con excel....

Comment: Javi fer2 he realizado lo que me indicas, ya elimine uno de los registros utilizando el notepad, lo guarde y volvi a ejecutar. El resultado el mismo fallo. Entonces como podria cambiarle la codificacion que sea similar a la que le da el excel?

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer con notePad++ seguramente. Al abrir el archivo verás la codificación que tiene uno que has guardado en excel y uno que no. Ahora bien, si es algo recurrente, tendrás que pedirle a la fuente de los csv, que te los entregue con esa codificación. Y si no lo hace, puedes aplicar un powershell antes de ejecutar el paquete. Nota: cuidado con los caracteres "raros" si cambias la codificación.